# Cómo enviar valores NULL a SP desde .NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, ado.net

Tengo un `stored procedure` que hace un `select`. Este `SP` lo uso para un formulario de búsqueda el cual si no se pasan parámetros para búsqueda me devuelve todos los registros. En otro caso se filtran algunos campos como fechas que son de tipo `DATE`. De cualquier manera tengo que enviar los campos si no son con valores tendría que enviarlos con `NULL`. El problema es que, como paso valores tipo `DATE` en `NULL`, me marca un error de que no se puede convertir. Lo he intentado hacer de la siguiente manera, pero no he conseguido llenar mi `GV`. ¿Hay otra forma de hacer esto?

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Util.ObtenerCadenaConexion("ConnectionString"));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "ProcListarAnuncio";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", txtTitulo.Text.Trim() == "" ? null : txtTitulo.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDesde", txtFechaI.Text.Trim() == "" ? null : txtFechaI.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaHasta", txtFechaF.Text.Trim() == "" ? null : txtFechaF.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de usar `null`, debes pasarle `DBNull.Value`. Aunque un poco raro, esa es la forma de pasarle `NULL` a los parámetros en ADO.NET:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", txtTitulo.Text.Trim() == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtTitulo.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDesde", txtFechaI.Text.Trim() == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtFechaI.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaHasta", txtFechaF.Text.Trim() == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtFechaF.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: me marca un error si coloco DBNull ->type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between ''system.DBNull ans string

Comment: Ah si, se me olvidó ese pequeño detalle. Modifiqué la respuesta para corregir el problema. Se necesita un cast a `object` para que el compilador no se queje.